# unittest - compare list irrespective of order

Tags: python, unit-testing

I am doing a unit test on two list of list values:

```
self.assertEqual(sale, [['1',14], ['2',5], ['3',7], ['4',1]])
```

But it gives the below error:

```
AssertionError: Lists differ: [['1', 14], ['4', 1], ['2', 5], ['3', 7]] != [['1'
, 14], ['2', 5], ['3', 7], ['4', 1]]

First differing element 1:
['4', 1]
['2', 5]

- [['1', 14], ['4', 1], ['2', 5], ['3', 7]]
+ [['1', 14], ['2', 5], ['3', 7], ['4', 1]]
```

How can I make this scenario pass, Prevent the assertEqual function to avoid checking the order of the elements in the list.

Comment: You could sort them, you could compare their lengths and compare them as sets, etc.

Comment: @chrisz. Option 2 is no good: `1, 1, 2` vs `1, 2, 2`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since Python lists keep track of order, you'll need some way to make sure the items are in the same order.

A set might work, if all items are unique. If they aren't unique you'll lose information on the duplicates.

Sorting the lists before you compare them will probably be your best bet. It will keep all the data intact, and put them in the same order in each list.

Here is a link to the different built in sorting methods for lists in Python 3.
https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sorting.html

Comment: Hmm, I think I answered the first part of your question; "how can I make this scenario pass" but not the second "prevent the assertEqual function to avoid checking the order of the elements in the list."

Comment: I think your answer is perfectly fine. I don't know why you got a downvote. The second part makes no actual sense. If you don't want to modify the originals, just use `sorted` instead of in-place sort.

Answer (score 7):

You want [`assertCountEqual`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase.assertCountEqual).

For `assertCountEqual(a, b)`, it passes if:

> a and b have the same elements in the same number, regardless of their order.