# Unittest - Compare list of lists without order

Tags: python, python-unittest

My question is similar to [unittest - compare list irrespective of order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50091784/unittest-compare-list-irrespective-of-order), but slightly different:

I have a function that returns a list of lists, without any guaranteed order (for both levels). I'm comparing its output to some predetermined value "this should be the answer" to test it. So if `should_be_the_answer == [[1,2], [3,4]]`, it should pass on the following returns:

`[[1,2], [3,4]]` - `[[3,4], [1,2]]` - `[[2,1], [4,3]]` - `[[3,4], [2,1]]` (and some more variants)

But not when mixing, so `[[1,3], [2,4]]` should fail.

`assertCountEqual` will not work, as it would compare the sublists (comparing the first with the last will tell me `[1,2]` is not in the last list).
All my values are unique, but instead of `int`s they are `dict`s, making conversion into a set awkward.

EDIT: Some example as to what I would want to compare. They are telephone numbers, with different interpretation due to uncertainty from which country they are called:

```
[{'source': '001123456789',
  'interpretations': [
     {'prefix': '00',
      'country_code': '1',
      'national_part': '123456789'},
     {'prefix': '0011',
      'country_code': '234',
      'national_part': '56789'}]
 }, {'source': '0011987654321',
  'interpretations': [
     {'prefix': '00',
      'country_code': '1',
      'national_part': '1987654321'},
     {'prefix': '0011',
      'country_code': '98',
      'national_part': '7654321'}]
}]
```

Comparing the source part is not a problem, but the different interpretations is.

What would be the best way to solve this?

I've come up with a few solutions, but none of them feel quite pythonic, and would probably be inefficient:

- Turn the sublists into sets, use the `repr` of the dicts to make this possible. But it feels wrong to turn them into strings just to compare them. And might lead to bugs if the order of the dict changes.
- Sort the list and/or sublists. Would mean coming up with a sorting/comparing function for the dicts, that's probably overkill.
- Loop over the sublists. For each value, try if there is a corresponding sublist that satisfies `assertCountEqual`. Would work, but when the output gets largers this has the potential to become very expensive (though it would probably work for my use-case)

Anyone has some better idea?

Comment: My first attempt in the past has been to sort the items so they come out in a predictable order. Can you update your question with a couple of sample `dict`s to see what would need to be done?

Comment: your example is not valid, curly braces are mismatched

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to implement what you need.

tl;dr: instead of `repr()` your dicts you can convert them to frozensets

```py
expected1 = [[1, 2], [3, 4]]
data1 = [[2, 1], [4, 3]]

def unorder(data, is_dict=False):
    if is_dict:
        return set(frozenset(frozenset(d.items()) for d in sublist) for sublist in data) # d is dict here
    else:
        return set(frozenset(sublist) for sublist in data)


assert unorder(data1) == unorder(expected1)
d1 = {'a': 1}
d2 = {'b': 2, 'x': 12}
d3 = {'c': 3}
d4 = {'d': 4, 'y': -23}
expected2 = [[d1, d2], [d3, d4]]
data2 = [[d2, d1], [d4, d3]]

assert unorder(data2, is_dict=True) == unorder(expected2, is_dict=True)
```

I use frozensets because you can add a frozenset to another set since they're
immutable.

Comment: Not easy to apply to the example data posted in the question, as there are `lists` inside the `dicts`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think sorting would be overkill. It can be done quite easily:

```
def mysort(l):
    l2 = sorted(l, key=lambda x: x["source"])
    for entry in l2:
        entry["interpretations"].sort(key=lambda x: x["prefix"])
    return l2

assert mysort(a) == mysort(b)
```

Currently this only uses `prefix` as a sort-key, which works with your example data, but might not be enough for real data.
Just use a combined key like `f"{x['prefix']}-{x['country_code']}"` in that case.

Performance, using just the interpretations-part: `test=example_data[0]["interpretations"]`:

```
# Creating a set from the list and frozensets from the dicts, as suggested in another answer:
timeit.timeit(lambda test=test: set(frozenset(d.items()) for d in test), number=1000000)
1.0023461619994123

# Sorting by single custom key:
timeit.timeit(lambda test=test: test.sort(key=lambda x: x["prefix"]), number=1000000)
0.32801106399983837

# Sorting by combined custom key:
timeit.timeit(lambda test=test: test.sort(key=lambda x: f"{x['prefix']}-{x['country_code']}"), number=1000000)
0.5157679960002497
```

Comment: Just realized my combined key wasn't unique. Updated answer with corrected key.